# How to display values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to create a dictionary of weigths per layer for my ANN implementation.

The issue is that although I create the dictionary with strings as keys and tensors as values I don't know how to display them when I call the `init_weight` method

```
def init_weights(topology):
#topology: dimensions of the network

for i in range(1,len(topology)):
parameters['W' + str(i)] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([topology[i-1],topology[i]]))
```

The output of the method shows the following:

```
{'W1': <tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(2, 5) dtype=float32_ref>,
 'W2': <tf.Variable 'Variable_3:0' shape=(5, 5) dtype=float32_ref>,
 'W3': <tf.Variable 'Variable_5:0' shape=(5, 5) dtype=float32_ref>,
 'W4': <tf.Variable 'Variable_7:0' shape=(5, 10) dtype=float32_ref>}
```

How can print the weights matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow is a statically typed framework (guess this is changing in 2.0). Meaning, you first build a static graph and the graph has values only when run using Tf.Session(). Now to answer your question. There are two ways to get what you want.

1. Add `tf.enable_eager_execution()` at the start of your script. This creates a dynamic graph (similar to Pytorch). Your same code without any extra addition will give you what you want.
2. Wrap everything into a `tf.Session()` and run it. You will get the weight matrices